# Using query params in Azure functions and Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Functions to retrieve data from a Cosmos DB. No I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.city = {city} AND r.district = {district} AND r.max_number_of_people = {people}
```

When I make a request using these as the query params: "?city=Amsterdam&district=West&people=2" I'm not getting anything back. I tried it without the people param, and then it works.

I think it has something to do with the max_number_of_people being saved as a number in my container, but I'm not sure.

What could be the issue here?

```
// function.json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "req",
      "route": "restaurants/available",
      "authLevel": "function",
      "methods": ["get"],
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "httpTrigger"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "restaurants",
      "databaseName": "find-your-spot",
      "collectionName": "restaurants",
      "connectionStringSetting": "fys-d-cdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.city = {city} AND r.district = {district} AND r.max_number_of_people = {people}",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "cosmosDB"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// index.js
module.exports = async function (context, req, restaurants) {
  try {
    context.res.status(200).json(restaurants);
  } catch (error) {
    context.res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a way to accomplish what I want. It may not be the only way.

```
SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.city = {city} AND r.district = {district} AND ToString(r.max_number_of_people) = {people}
```